# system() call is returning wrong value in C

Tags: c, linux, system

I am getting a -1 return value, even after running a command successfully via system() call.
Please see the following C code for more information.

```
system("ping -w 3 -c 1 -q -I 63.254.203.24 63.254.203.26 >/dev/null");
```

and then I am checking the return value of this system() call, even though it is pingable but I found -1 as a return value.

Comment: Are you sure ping is run successfully? Check if redirecting output to some file really creates this file with expected content.

Comment: ping is running successfully.

Answer (score 7):

to see the actual return value use `WEXITSTATUS(n)` and the reason why `system` doesn't return the actual value is because (and this is only valid for linux) it is implemented using `fork` , `exec` and `wait` the later returns the status of the process which contains whether the process ended normally or because of a signal plus the actual return value , and to access those different values you'll have to use macro's such as `WEXITSTATUS(n)` these macros are mentioned in `man 3 wait`

The section RETURN VALUE of `man system` :

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status  is
>   in the  format  specified  in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the
>   command will be `WEXITSTATUS(status)`.  In case /bin/sh could not be
>   executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does
>   `exit(127)`.

Comment: You could also cite some words from the section "RETURN VALUE" of manual page of `man 3 system`.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I got the answer. it was fork failed due to memory failure. 
It is not a good idea to use system() call.

Thanks for the support and answer.